# How finding out the subtraction containing inside a folder?

Tags: java, directory

Getting error for what it could not be the place of the other stuff. That is the subtraction thing?

Comment: Nothing to do with your jvm version

Comment: Can you show the entire 'error'? I assume a stack trace...

Comment: @SteveSiebert It only creates a compile time error, which I described in the original post.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Could you help out please?

Answer (score 0):

You should declare the filepath variable as a File in the scope of this.

Comment: No, you don't need to declare it. Also, the type is Path, not File. (File is an older class that doesn't work with the Java 7 methods you are calling in your example)

Comment: So what happens if you apply the Quick Fix, and actually create a local variable 'filePath'?

Answer (score 0):

It works on my machine. You do need to be on Java 8 for that to work since lambdas didn't exist in Java 7.

Also, note that you could make that be more functional programming and get rid of the if statement entirely:

```
Files.walk(path).filter(filePath -> Files.isRegularFile(filePath))
                .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you testing your jvm version?  What do you get back when you type javac -version? (I'm wondering if your java binary is linked to your 1.8 install but your javac is still linked to <1.8)